# How to pull nested document from the array of documents in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to remove a nested objects array in my document. The scenario is that i am searching for the days an event will be organised for, by using its eventid

```
const { eventid, typesOfTicketId } = req.params;
const eventDays = await EventDate.find({event: eventid});
```

Here eventid is passed from params as "5e9c0f0593ab3c058e282bfa". I then want to remove a requested day from the nested objects array. From the above query, I am receiving an array of dates and on each index of array the document is in this format:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7f54b8b22480431f1a455"),
    "day" : "1588186800",
    "typesOfTicket" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7f54b8b22480431f1a456"),
            "ticket" : "Adult Tickets",
            "noTickets" : 40,
            "price" : 50,
            "ticketsLeft" : 40
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7f54b8b22480431f1a457"),
            "ticket" : "Children Tickets",
            "noTickets" : 50,
            "price" : 30,
            "ticketsLeft" : 50
        }
    ],
    "event" : ObjectId("5e9c0f0593ab3c058e282bfa"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7f5678b22480431f1a45f"),
    "day" : "1588273200",
    "typesOfTicket" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7f5678b22480431f1a460"),
            "ticket" : "Male Tickets",
            "noTickets" : 50,
            "price" : 5,
            "ticketsLeft" : 50
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7f5678b22480431f1a461"),
            "ticket" : "Female Tickets",
            "noTickets" : 50,
            "price" : 5,
            "ticketsLeft" : 50
        }
    ],
    "event" : ObjectId("5e9c0f0593ab3c058e282bfa"),
    "__v" : 0
}]
```

What i want is to find a way to remove the document in the nested typesOfTicket array, like lets say i want to remove the Object with id: typesOfTicketId. (e.g typesOfTicketId = "5ea7f5678b22480431f1a461"), the female ticket one by passing its ID.

I have already tried this query:

```
await EventDate.update({event: eventid}, {
   $pull: {
      typesOfTicket: {
         _id: "typesOfTicketIDHERE"
      }
   }
});
```

But the above given query is only working if i am removing the first index of eventDays Array, like if i am deleting the ID: "5ea7f54b8b22480431f1a456", then this will work but if i am going for the  id's on the second index like "Female tickets"/"5ea7f5678b22480431f1a461", then it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, the above query did work correctly after just some adjustments

```
await EventDate.update({event: eventid}, {
   $pull: {
      typesOfTicket: {
         _id: "typesOfTicketIDHERE"
      }
   }
}, { multi: true });
```

Just specifying the multi params to true will do the trick.